# How can I get the resolution inputted in a XxY format?

Tags: javascript, string, input

I'm building an application and users need to input a resolution for calling a functions, since it's string-based I can't just ask it with a beautiful UI, and it'd be too tedious to ask height and width separately, so, is there a way to do that? I first tried using `split("x")` and accessing the values with `res[0]` and `res[1]` but it didn't work.

Below you can find a code snippet of the example I gave before (splitting).

```js
const getRes = (res) => {
  let resSplitted = res.toString().split("x");
  console.log("x: " + parseInt(resSplitted[0]) + "| y: " + parseInt(resSplitted[1]))
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="res" placeholder="Resolution (XxY)"><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="getRes(document.getElementById('res'))">
```

Comment: Please show the code you used that didn't work as a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to create something that everyone can run and try out.

Comment: I don't see why splitting on `"x"` would be a problem. What didn't work? Maybe you forgot to convert those strings to numbers? (ex: `const width = parseInt(res[0], 10);`)

Comment: I've added a code snippet showing the example I gave in the post and why it fails.

Comment: `res` is a text object. You need to get its value: `let resSplitted = res.value.split("x");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
{
  let [x, y] = "123x456".split("x");
  console.log(+x, +y); // + converts to number
}
```